# Keyframing "Use Count" in a particle system

Tags: particles

I'm currently trying to keyframe the ratio of objects emitted by a collection particle system (e.g. the particle system emits a set of objects in a collection). The "Count" property within the "Use Count" section has a tick next to it indicating the property can be animated, but when I try to animate it, I get the error "failed to resolve path to property."

Is this just a bug in Blender's 2.8 release candidate, or is there something I'm missing?

Comment: it sounds like a bug to me.

Comment: 2.79 has the same issue, I say it is a bug but expect the solution will be to make that value not-animatable.

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately this is still a bug all these years later. https://developer.blender.org/T71732